# Tumblr Theme: toggle show div by clicking on thumbnail photo

Tags: jquery

Here's the demo page: http://froitheme.tumblr.com/

JSfiddle without tumblr tags: https://jsfiddle.net/3ggvmy40/7/

[This JSfiddle isn't working for some reason, even though the demo page on is.]

Anyway, I'm trying to create a gallery style index page, with thumbnail posts on the left and the full post on the right once one thumbnail is clicked.

As you can see, only the latest post shows up when clicked, while the previous post stays blank.

Please help! Tumblr uses the `{PostID}` tag to distinguish between posts which renders as a long number sequence and that's what I'm trying to target to make sure only one post shows up at a time and that the thumbnail corresponds with the full post, though this only works for the latest post and nothing before it.

The JS:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    var target = "#" + $(this).attr("data-target");
    $(".posting").not(target).hide();
    $(target).fadeToggle("slow");
});

$('.posting').hide();
```

The HTML:

```
    <section id="content">
        {block:Posts}
            {block:Photo}
            <a href="#" id="link" data-target="{PostID}">
            <div class="post">
            <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" />
            </div>
            </a>
            {/block:Photo}
        {/block:Posts}
    </section>

    <section id="side">
        <div id="nav">
            this will go here!
        </div>
        {block:Posts}
            {block:Photo}
            <div class="posting" id="{PostID}">
            <img src="{PhotoURL-400}" />
            </div>
            {/block:Photo}
        {/block:Posts}
    </section>
```

The CSS:

```
    #content {
        float: left;
        width: 740px;
        height: 520px;
        background: transparent;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .post {
        opacity: 0.5;
        float: right;
        margin: 0px 18px 17px 0px;
        padding: 50px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #side {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 16px;
        width: 480px;
        height: 520px;
        background: #000;
    }

    .posting {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 40px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 480px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    #nav {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 40px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 480px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Thanks for actually clicking on this!

Comment: "As you can see, only the latest post shows up when clicked, while the previous post stays blank."
What do you mean by this?

Comment: if you click on the demo, only the picture of Patrick shows up on the right when you click on its thumbnail, whereas the original post picture next to it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using duplicate ids:

```
<a href="#" id="link"
```

Use class instead:

```
<a href="#" class="link"
```

and

```
$('.link').click(function(){
```

Comment: jfc i can't believe that was it. I didn't even think to change that because the id were in separate divs. Thank you so much!